# Update/Insert trigger in the same table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I'm kind of new to this but want to write some first simple trigger.
If I have mytable with  fields A,B,C.
When user inserts or updates A and B, I want to update  C=A+B by trigger
would it be easy? thanks

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Don't use a trigger for this. You can always retrieve that sum when doing a select. You meight want to consider a view for convenience. In general: never store values in a database that can be derived from the existing values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trigger that will do as you ask. Since there is a lack of ID column in mytable, there is no way to specify only update c for the rows that have been updated (i.e. the value of `c` will be recalculated for every row on every insert/update).

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
ON mytable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE mytable
    SET    c = COALESCE(a, 0) + COALESCE(b, 0)
```

This would be a suitable candidate for a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
  (
     a INT,
     b INT,
     c AS COALESCE(a, 0) + COALESCE(b, 0)
  )
```

**Edit**: Example with ID column to only update `c` for updated/inserted rows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
ON mytable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE mytable
    SET    c = COALESCE(a, 0) + COALESCE(b, 0)
    WHERE  ID IN (SELECT ID
                  FROM   inserted)
```

I've created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e571/3) where you can see this live.

To run you through the SQL Fiddle example:

1. Create schema, add some sample data, then add the trigger definition
   (so `c` is unpopulated at this point).
2. Select from the table, so you can see the example values.
3. Update a row, and then select from the table again (you can see `c`
   has now been populated).
4. Insert a new row, then select everything from the table again (`c`
   has been populated for this new row).

To explain a bit more about how this works - during trigger execution, SQL server (I'm assuming by now that is what you're using) creates two temporary tables `inserted` and `deleted` with copies of the affected rows in - we can join or select from those tables if we need to get data from them; in this case just getting a list of the ids that were affected by the update/insert operation and then only updating `c` for those rows. For more detail on this, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).

Comment: That trigger would update every row every time anything was updated. That is bound to be a performance problem. The computed column is the right choice anyway (you may want it persisted though at least in SQL Server).

Comment: @HLGEM Yes I know, I mentioned that in my answer already - I'm assuming it's a learning exercise and OP just wanted to know how it could be done. I know with a proper ID column you could join onto the `inserted` table in the trigger to only update the relevant rows, but no such column was mentioned in the example schema. Good point about `persisted`, but OP still hasn't answered on the question of which RDBMS they're using! ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It's a more complex computation. I am trying to learn the concept first (MS SQL 2008). It's a database of an ERP software so we have no control of the structure. I just want to have this C field computed and wasn't sure how this trigger work. Yes I should have mentioned the ID col. If it is update action, where do I find the matching a&b? in mytable? do I need to 'select' in inserted if it is insert? <br>CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
ON mytable
FOR INSERT
AS   UPDATE mytable
    SET    c = COALESCE(select a from inserted i where i.id=id,0)+ COALESCE(select b from inserted i where i.id=id,0)

Comment: @HoangMN I've updated my answer to include an example with an id column, with a live demo and explanations.